# Idea Hunt, FPGA + ARM Cortex-M3

Tags: fpga, arm, cortex-m3

I aim to demonstrate the need for FPGAs as compared to MPUs like (e.g. ARM Cortex-M3 based from TI/ST) in doing processing intensive stuff. I am looking for some help in this regard. I want to show that a design based on MPUs + FPGA will be more faster (feasible?).

The following is what i have come up with till now,

1. Comparing N-Point FFTs
2. Compare designs based on Cordic
3. Huge Calculations based on Fixed/Floating points Systems. (ALU Design)

Are there more novel applications where the FPGA + MPU design achieves much more than a single MPU ? It would be great to have some stuff pointed at. Happy to read as always :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some fields that benefit of higher processing capabilities of FPGAs:

- Image processing (filtering, object recognition)
- HPC (High performance computing)
- Advanced filtering (Kalman, etc)
- SDR (software defined radio)

Answer (score 1):

This is an opinion/debate question, and as such, isn't really a good fit for the SE format.

However, I'll offer one application that might fit your needs, and that's the area of machine vision, especially with high-definition sensors. The FPGA is very good at accelerating the basic image processing, such as sensor corrections, noise removal, linear and nonlinear filtering, equalization, data reduction etc., while a high-performance DSP or MCU is a better fit for the more computationally-intensive tasks such as geometry corrections, edge/feature recognition and tracking.